# No implicit Ordering defined for ord

Tags: scala, generics, typeclass, implicit, context-bound

I want to define a collection class and require its element being `Ordered`

Considering the code below:

```
class MyCollection[K: Ordered[K]] {
  def func(seq: Seq[K]): Unit = {
    seq.sorted
  }
}
```

The compiler will report error `No implicit Ordering defined for ord: Ordering[K]`

Am I doing anything wrong? Given that we already have the constraint `K: Ordered[K]`

Comment: Just use `Ordering` instead of `Ordered`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

- either `Ordered` with

  - [F-bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339548/scala-f-bounded-types-explanation)

    ```
    class MyCollection[K <: Ordered[K]] {
      def func(seq: Seq[K]): Unit =
        seq.sorted
    }
    ```
  - [generalized constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75762318/in-scala-3-is-it-possible-to-make-covariant-contravariant-type-constructor-to-h)

    ```
    class MyCollection[K](implicit ev: K <:< Ordered[K]) {
      def func(seq: Seq[K]): Unit =
        seq.sorted
    }
    ```
  - [view bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds)

    ```
    class MyCollection[K](implicit ev: K => Ordered[K]) {
      def func(seq: Seq[K]): Unit =
        seq.sorted
    }
    ```

    (from stronger to weaker assumption)
- or `Ordering` with [context bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala)

  ```
  class MyCollection[K: Ordering] {
    def func(seq: Seq[K]): Unit =
      seq.sorted
  }
  ```

`Ordered` and `Ordering` are now defined so that the constraints  `K => Ordered[K]` and `K: Ordering` are actually equivalent. Indeed, [`Ordering.ordered`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.10/src/library/scala/math/Ordering.scala#L218-L220) transforms one into another in one direction, [`Ordered.orderingToOrdered`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.10/src/library/scala/math/Ordered.scala#L99-L100) transforms in the other

```
def test[K](implicit ev: K => Ordered[K]) =
  implicitly[Ordering[K]] // compiles

def test[K: Ordering] =
  implicitly[K => Ordered[K]] // compiles
```

The context bound `MyCollection[K: Ordering]` is a syntax sugar for `MyCollection[K](implicit ev: Ordering[K])`.
That's why `[K: Ordered[K]]` can't compile at all because of kind mismatch.

`Ordering` is a [type class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408861/what-are-type-classes-in-scala-useful-for) but `Ordered` is not. `Ordered` is an ordinary OOP trait (you're extending it in OOP style rather than define its implicit instances in FP style).
That's why although `[K: Ordered]` compiles but it would be incorrect semantically (implicits will not be found).

[Ordering and Ordered and comparing Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600154/ordering-and-ordered-and-comparing-options)

[Scala Ordering, Ordered, and View Bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793262/scala-ordering-ordered-and-view-bound)

[Get Ordering from Ordered in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43439405/get-ordering-from-ordered-in-scala)